# No lo conozco - Why does the lo mean 'he'?

Tags: pronombres

I am studying Spanish with Michel Thomas Method. It says the following:

```
I don’t know him. = No lo conozco.
```

I don't understand this? I thought `lo` means `it`. Shouldn't it be `le`? If not, then when do you use `lo` to mean `he`?

Comment: You use `lo` for `he` when there exists no direct object. `le`, when used with a verb as an indirect object, can translate to `to him/her/it` and `for him/her/it`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `he` is the direct object.  And the masculine direct object is lo.  Although, you could still get away with saying `No le conozco`, it would mean more like

> I don't know him know him.'

or

> He isn't known to me.

As in, I don't know how he is as a person... ,I haven't gotten to know him.
Whereas, `no lo conozco` is straightforward don't know who he is.

---

### Cortesía

As mentioned by guifa, `LE` in that context can also express courtesy.  While `lo` can, as you mentioned in your OP big_smile, refer to *it*.. and if you're trying to be formal, you definitely don't want to refer to someone as *it*

Comment: So is it best not to think of `lo` as being equal to `it`, but more of a general pronoun that can stand for anything? If so, when do you know when to use `lo` and `le`?

Comment: Although `lo` can be translated to `it` in English... *it* simply refers to an object, a person, a place, or a thing.

Comment: `Le` is an indirect object.

Comment: this should help you http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/indirectobject.htm

Comment: @dockerys le is *normally* an indirect object, but for some speakers it can function as a direct object.  For users of the leísmo de cortesía, pretty common in the Americas, *le conozco* would be "I don't know you, sir/ma'am", whereas *lo conozco* would be "I don't know him".

Comment: @guifa wouldn't `no lo conozco` be `I don't know him`?

Comment: @big_smile err, yes, both of my Spanish sentences needed a *no* in front (or the English ones needed to be in the affirmative). This is what I get for typing things out when I need to be in bed.

Comment: Right @guifa, I did forget about that.  CORTESÍA

Comment: @guifa Thanks, I was just double checking because in some languages, `no` can be omitted. Thank goodness that isn't the case in Spanish, as it gets very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In "no lo conozco", the "lo" stands for "him". Therefore making it I don't know "him"  as opposed to "no conozco" which would just mean "I don't know".